# Images as a link from css

Tags: image

I wanted to place an image in my browser through the css file.

Eg: I have an image called "Save". I don want to have any image tags in my html, whereas I have to place it from css inside an  tag..in the html (i.e. the image tag must be present in css file but i have to call it in the html) ??

Is that possible..
Can anyone guide me with that ??

Comment: This site is helpful for teaching yourself HTML/CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Answer (score 2):

#### HTML

```
<a id="save" href="save.php">Save</a>
```

#### CSS

```
#save {
   display: block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background: url(/images/save.png) no-repeat;
   text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: The problem here is there should not be any text between the <a> tag.. like how you have given Save between <a> </a>. That should not be there..

Comment: @user533329 The `text-indent` attribute causes the text not to be visible for browsers (but still visible to web robots), showing only the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use input tag

```
<input type = 'image' value = 'Save' src = 'save.jpg' >
```